# Extracting value coded in an equation from text file

Tags: python

in a text file I have a specific line like:

```
ZONE, T="test", I =100, J=  175, F = POINT
```

and I want to extract with python the values for "I" and "J".

```
I = ** your code **
J = ** your code **
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: clean white space, split on commas, look for 'I=' and 'J=', take what comes after

Answer (score 0):

for example I are writed in a text file name filename.txt , on this File it is writted I = 100 , i will use re.search for find the value

```
import re

f = open('filename.txt', 'a').readlines()
for i in f:
   value = i.rstrip()
   n = re.search(r'I = (.*)', value)
   i = n.group(1)
   print("I = " + i)
```